# Separating individual mails from mail trail in using Python

Tags: python, email

I am working on email related PoC using Python. System receives email which contains mail trail.I wanted to separate the individual emails from the mail trail and process them. Issue is I am not getting right code or library to do it. Can anybody please help.

For e.g.
System get email like below

```
SUBJECT: RE: CALL ID #  98670786 CALL ID #  98983051 DATE SENT: 23-JANUARY-2017 TIME SENT: 17:56:09 PM SENDER ID: abc@xyz.COM MESSAGE TEXT: DEAR SIR, 

Please check and let me know 
REGARDS 

XXXXXXX 
00000015 

FROM: company;sender@company.COM 
SENT:MON, 23 JAN 2017 16:04:26 +0530 
TO: abc@xyz.COM 
SUBJECT: RE: RE: CALL ID #  98670786 CALL ID #  98983051 
DEAR MR. XXXXX, 
> 
>WE REFER TO YOUR EMAIL DATED 20/01/2017 FOR THE company. 
> 
>WE HEREBY INFORM YOU THAT WE HAVE CHECKED WITH OUR TOUCH POINT AND THEY HAVE CONFIRMED THAT THE Things HAS BEEN delivered TO YOU AND WE WOULD KINDLY REQUEST YOU TO CHECK YOUR at your end FOR BETTER ASSISTANCE. 
> 
>  
> 
>YOURS SINCERELY, 
> 
>sender, 
>Company
>---------------------------------------------------------- 
>Disclaimers: 
>adsadsadsadadasdada 
>daadsadadsadsadsa.  
>REGISTERED ADDRESS:-sadsadsadsadsadsadsadasdsadsadsadsa  
>---------------ORIGINAL MESSAGE------------------ 
>SUBJECT: CALL ID # 98418758 CALL ID # 98510240 CALL ID # 98670786 DATE SENT: 20-JANUARY-2017 TIME SENT: 11:06:38 AM SENDER ID: abc@xyz.COM MESSAGE TEXT: DEAR SIR, 
> 
>BY WHEN WILL THIS things WILL BE delivered TO Me. 
> 
>REGARDS 
> 
>XXXXXXX 
> 
>00000015 
> 
>FROM: "company"sender@company.COM 
>SENT:FRI, 20 JAN 2017 10:44:16 +0530 
>TO: abc@xyz.COM 
>SUBJECT: RE: RE: CALL ID # 98510240 CALL ID # 98670786 
>DEAR MR. XXXXX, WE APPRECIATE YOUR TIME AND PATIENCE AND APOLOGIZE FOR THE LATE RESPONSE. 
>> 
>>WE REFER TO YOUR EMAIL DATED 11/01/2017N FOR company NUMBER 00000015. WITH REGARDS TO YOUR CONCERN WE HEREBY INFORM YOU THAT TILL DATE YOUR things is pending with us.  
>>TRUST THIS CLARIFIES YOUR CONCERN. YOURS SINCERELY, 
>> 
>>Sender. 
>>company 
>>---------------------------------------------------------- 
>>CALL CENTER TIMINGS: 10.00 A.M. TO 7.00 P.M MONDAY TO SATURDAY (EXCEPT NATIONAL HOLIDAYS)
```

The above mail should be split in four parts like below

1)

```
SUBJECT: RE: CALL ID #  98670786 CALL ID #  98983051 DATE SENT: 23-JANUARY-2017 TIME SENT: 17:56:09 PM SENDER ID: abc@xyz.COM MESSAGE TEXT: DEAR SIR, 

Please check and let me know 

REGARDS 

XXXXXXX 
00000015
```

2)

```
FROM: company;sender@company.COM 
SENT:MON, 23 JAN 2017 16:04:26 +0530 
TO: abc@xyz.COM 
SUBJECT: RE: RE: CALL ID #  98670786 CALL ID #  98983051 
DEAR MR. XXXXX, 
> 
>WE REFER TO YOUR EMAIL DATED 20/01/2017 FOR THE company. 
> 
>WE HEREBY INFORM YOU THAT WE HAVE CHECKED WITH OUR TOUCH POINT AND THEY HAVE CONFIRMED THAT THE Things HAS BEEN delivered TO YOU AND WE WOULD KINDLY REQUEST YOU TO CHECK YOUR at your end FOR BETTER ASSISTANCE. 
> 
>   
> 
>YOURS SINCERELY, 
> 
>sender, 
>Company
>---------------------------------------------------------- 
>Disclaimers
>adsadsadsadadasdada 
>daadsadadsadsadsa.  
>REGISTERED ADDRESS:-sadsadsadsadsadsadsadasdsadsadsadsa
```

3)

```
>---------------ORIGINAL MESSAGE------------------ 
>SUBJECT: CALL ID # 98418758 CALL ID # 98510240 CALL ID # 98670786 DATE SENT: 20-JANUARY-2017 TIME SENT: 11:06:38 AM SENDER ID: abc@xyz.COM MESSAGE TEXT: DEAR SIR, 
> 
>BY WHEN WILL THIS things WILL BE delivered TO Me. 
> 
>REGARDS 
> 
>XXXXXXX 
> 
>00000015 
>
```

4)

```
>FROM: "company"sender@company.COM 
>SENT:FRI, 20 JAN 2017 10:44:16 +0530 
>TO: abc@xyz.COM 
>SUBJECT: RE: RE: CALL ID # 98510240 CALL ID # 98670786 
>DEAR MR. XXXXX, WE APPRECIATE YOUR TIME AND PATIENCE AND APOLOGIZE FOR THE LATE RESPONSE. 
>> 
>>WE REFER TO YOUR EMAIL DATED 11/01/2017N FOR company NUMBER 00000015. WITH REGARDS TO YOUR CONCERN WE HEREBY INFORM YOU THAT TILL DATE YOUR things is pending with us.  
>>TRUST THIS CLARIFIES YOUR CONCERN. YOURS SINCERELY, 
>> 
>>Sender. 
>>company 
>>---------------------------------------------------------- 
>>CALL CENTER TIMINGS: 10.00 A.M. TO 7.00 P.M MONDAY TO SATURDAY (EXCEPT NATIONAL HOLIDAYS)
```

**------ EDITED -----**
After lots of permutation, I have come with following code.

```
startMsgPatter=
re.compile((\W*ORIGINAL\s*MESSAGE|\W*FROM\s*:|\W*ON.*WROTE\s*:)")
def sperateEmails(callDesc):
    itr = startMsgPatter.finditer(callDesc)
    blockStart = 0
    emails = []

    while True:
        m = next(itr,None)
        if not m:
            break
        blockEnd = m.start()
        if blockStart >= blockEnd:
            continue 
        emailPart = callDesc[blockStart:blockEnd]
        emails.append(emailPart)
        blockStart = blockEnd
        emails.append(callDesc[blockStart:len(callDesc)])
    return emails
```

It is working but I have to keep on finding the patterns indicating start and end of the mail and update it. As per me, this mail trails should be following certain patterns. Do anybody has written a code considering most of such patterns, please share it.

Comment: Can you please give an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function **split()**

Example:

```
"first mail separator second mail".split(" separator ")
```

Will outpout:

> ["first mail", "second mail"]

You just have to know which separator to use. Note that the separator will be removed from the result but if you need it, you can reappend it afterwards.

In your case, it seems like all messages are separated by the string

```
"---------------ORIGINAL MESSAGE------------------"
```

or

```
"FROM"
```

I suggest that you first split on the first one and then on the second like this:

```
all = [] # Splitted messages will be stored here
# mail_trail is the content of your mail trail
sep = mail_trail.split("---------------ORIGINAL MESSAGE------------------")
for msg in sep:
    sep2 = msg.split("FROM")
    if len(sep2) == 2: # has splitted
         sep2[1] = "FROM" + sep2[1] # reappend the FROM since you need it
    all.extend(sep2) # Add the messages in the array
```

This should put you on the right track.

Comment: Your code is quite working. But I am able to do it in some other way. I have posted my code in the question. Well extend() function didn't work properly in the code for me. It appended the list with individual characters from string argument. append() worked well for me.